# Plot 3D with conditions and variables dependent on each other

Tags: plotting

I m trying to do something like this:

```
Plot3D[x[s1, s2], 
  {s2, (m3^2 + m^2)^2, (Sqrt[s] -  m^2)^2}, {s1,s1min[s2], s1max[s2]}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x[s1, s2]}, -1 < x < 1]]
```

but without success.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The plot limits for `s1` and `s2` have to be constants, and your syntax for `Function` is wrong.  Try integrating the conditions on `s1` into the `RegionFunction`, something like `Function[{s1, s2, x}, -1 < x < 1 && s1min[s2] < s1 < s1max[s2]]`.

Comment: First of all, thks for the quick answer. So the problem is that s2 varies between numbers  and s1 varies a function of s2. So what I wanna do is plot the fucntion x that I already defined before but only if its between -1 and 1...hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ConditionalExpression` using all the conditions that define the region you want to plot as the second argument:

```
ClearAll[x, m, m3, s1min, s1max]
x[s1_, s2_] := Sin[s1 + s2];
m = Sqrt[Pi/32];
m3 = Sqrt[Pi/64];
s1min[s_] := Sqrt@s;
s1max[s_] := 2 + Sqrt@s;

Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[x[s1, s2], 
   (m3^2 + m^2)^2 <= s2 <= (Sqrt[s1] - m^2)^2 && 
   s1min[s2] <= s1 <= s1max[s2] && -1 < x[s1, s2] < 1], 
 {s1, 0, Pi}, {s2, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

or, use `RegionFunction`

```
Plot3D[x[s1, s2], {s1, 0, Pi}, {s2, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{s1, s2, z}, (m3^2 + m^2)^2 <= s2 <= (Sqrt[s1] - m^2)^2 && 
    s1min[s2] <= s1 <= s1max[s2] && -1 < z < 1]]
 (* same picture *)
```