# Conditional Plot of a function if another function satisfies something and in the case of complex variable

Tags: plotting, function-construction, complex

Let's say we have function $g(\zeta)$ and another map $f(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a complex variable. I am trying to plot a graph of $f(\zeta)$ but given the condition of $g(\zeta)$.

For instance, I am trying to have a command like: $$\text{plot}\ f(\zeta)\ \text{blue if}\ g(\zeta)\leq 1$$

A similar question has been asked here: [Conditional options in Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37468/conditional-options-in-plot)

I followed the answer in that question but I cannot get what I want. Here is what I have tried:

1. Firstly, I define the conditional plot command, as we are dealing with two variables $(\zeta=x+iy)$, I changed "plot" in the original command to contour plot.

   ```
   ConditionalPlot[fun_,condition_, varrange_, trueopts_, falseopts_] :=    
     Module[{plottrue, plotfalse}, 
       plottrue = ContourPlot[If[condition, func], varrange, trueopts];
       plotfalse = ContourPlot[If[Not[condition], func], varrange, falseopts]; 
       Show[plottrue, plotfalse, PlotRange -> All]]
   ```
2. Then, I used this command to plot:

   ```
   ConditionalPlot[f (x + Iy), g (x + Iy) <= 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},    
     {Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightGreen, PlotStyle -> Dashed}, 
     {Filling -> Axis,FillingStyle -> LightRed, PlotStyle -> Thick}]
   ```

However, the output of Mathematica is just the code I have entered, without producing the graph. I don't really know where the problem is.

I also tried to use explicit formula of f(x+Iy) and g(x+Iy) and the problem is still there.

I also tried this command:

```
ConditionalPlot[f (x + Iy),g (x + Iy) <= 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  {PlotStyle -> Dashed},{PlotStyle -> Thick}]
```

since I think maybe `Filling--Axis` is not right for contour plot, however it still cannot work.

Any idea is welcome! Thank you!

**I also tried another way to do this question**

The idea is from this post: [Plot 3D with conditions and variables dependent on each other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78346/plot-3d-with-conditions-and-variables-dependent-on-each-other)

Here is my command:

```
ContourPlot[
  ConditionalExpression[f (x + Iy), g (x + Iy) <= 3 && g (x + Iy) >= 1], 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

However, Mathematica then produced me a graph with nothing. Just empty. So I think there is something it cannot understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

There are quite a few minor errors in your code and, I think, two major ones:

- `f` and `g` have to be real-valued functions of a complex variable.
- you should be plotting `f` with `Plot3D` if you want to use options like `Filling`.

I also think that for `Plot3D`, the filling option `Filling -> Bottom` will give a better plot than `Filling -> Axis`.

Taking the above into account and fixing the minor errors as well, produces the following:

```
Clear[ConditionalPlot]
ConditionalPlot[func_, condition_, xrng_, yrng_, trueopts_, falseopts_] := 
  Module[{plottrue, plotfalse}, 
    plottrue = Plot3D[If[condition, func], xrng, yrng, trueopts];
    plotfalse = Plot3D[If[Not[condition], func], xrng, yrng, falseopts];
    Show[plottrue, plotfalse, PlotRange -> All]]

f[z_] := Re[z^2]
g[z_] := Im[z]

ConditionalPlot[f[x + I y], g[x + I y] <= 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  {Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> LightGreen, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Green, .2], Lighting -> "Neutral"},
  {Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> LightRed, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Red, .2], Lighting -> "Neutral"}]
```

[image: plot]

As to the matter you bring up in your comment this answer, what you suggest will work.

```
Clear[ConditionalPlot]
ConditionalPlot[func_, condition_, xrng_, yrng_, opts_] :=
  Module[{plottrue},
    plottrue = Plot3D[If[condition, func], xrng, yrng, opts];
    Show[plottrue]]

ConditionalPlot[f[x + I y], g[x + I y] <= 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  {Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> LightGreen, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Green, .2], Lighting -> "Neutral"}]
```

[image: plot2]

But don't think that now the use of `Module` and `Show` are overkill? Wouldn't the following, which gives the same plot, be better?

```
Clear[ConditionalPlot]
ConditionalPlot[func_, condition_, xrng_, yrng_, opts_] :=
  Plot3D[If[condition, func], xrng, yrng, opts]
```

Comment: Amazing!!! I have an another question that, what should I do if I want Mathematica do nothing if the condition is false?

Comment: Is that okay if I just remove plotfalse in the show command?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical. Does my edit address the issue you raise in your comments?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!!